# Referencing a Web Site from a WPF Project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, hybrid

My solution has two projects: a web site which points to a local folder with web files (html, css, js, etc). and a C# WPF application. I would like to have my html files be resources in my WPF Project but I can't figure out a way to do this.

Essentially I'd like to not have to copies of my html files anywhere but I'd like to reference them in my C# project.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on your project and select "Add Existing Item", on your file type drop down select "All Files" and finally on the "Add" drop down select "Add As Link".

Comment: +1 for this, never saw the little arrow next to the add button. But this isn't the best solution yet because I have to add files individually, I want to be able to reference an entire folder/project.

Comment: As far as I know it's the only practical solution.  Other than placing your "resources" into a common project and referencing the project in your web project as well as in your WPF project.  However, I wouldn't know how to access something like a CSS that's embedded in a dll.  You could try pack uri.